# how to run visual studio project in other computer which does not have visual studio installed in it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, deployment

i have made a visual studio project which is quite small. i want that it should be deployed in the customer's PC so i want to make a exe file of that. so that it should be installed and used correctly. how can i make an `.exe` or `.msi` file. i have just heard it some where i dont know how to. because i am a newbie i dont know much about visual studio i thougt it will help me to make exe file but after production i got i cant deploy my project as i have .cs files of forms. i am using `visual studio 2010 ultimate` and building project on `c#` language can i make .msi or .exe file so that it can be run in other computer also? and if yess then whats procedure

Comment: You could just read up on the subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtzawcsz(v=vs.100).aspx,

Answer (score 4):

When you compile your project, you will find `.exe` and (probably) `.dll` files in `bin\Debug` and `bin\Release`.

You can copy those files to a different computer and run the program, as long as it has the correct version of the .Net framework installed.

Comment: sir it also have mdf file in it. can i copy those files and run that exe. it will store all thing in that .mdf file? i dont have to give paths of mdf file if i saved that .mdf in other location?

Comment: sir apart from that which file can i use to take the database backup so that i can restore. i tried .mdf file but it doesnt work. i want full data to be stored which file to take backup of database? and if i want to creat .msi file how can i create that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install database on client computer.
2. Install your project on computer.
3. Make ODBC on computer.

   a. make DNS with sql server.

   b. make microsoft access driver.